# having trouble when implementing the interface 'Quantizer' and 'Drawer' of GIF

Tags: image, go, gif

In `image/draw`, `Quantizer` and `Drawer` are defined like this:

```golang
type Quantizer interface { 
    Quantize(p color.Palette, m image.Image) color.Palette 
}
type Drawer interface {
    Draw(dst Image, r image.Rectangle, src image.Image, sp image.Point)
}
```

And there are codes in `gif.Encode(w io.Writer, m image.Image, o *Options)` like this:

```golang
if opts.Quantizer != nil { 
    pm.Palette = opts.Quantizer.Quantize(make(color.Palette, 0, opts.NumColors), m) 
} 
opts.Drawer.Draw(pm, b, m, b.Min)
```

When I want to write an image quantization algorithm myself, I need to implement `draw.Quantizer` and `draw.Drawer`.

As you see, `opts.Quantizer.Quantize` returns the `Palette`. But actually, when calling `opts.Drawer.Draw`, I need not only the `Palette`, but also some other data from `Quantize`.

Is it possible to make the quantization data able to be used?

---

Edited on 25 Dec.

For example, I get an indexing map when `quantize`. When I `draw`, I need this indexing map to make my algorithm faster. What can I do to pass this indexing map into the `Drawer`?

Comment: I am not sure but the requirements seems missing in your question. Please add more details.

Comment: Ok, I added some details into my question. I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`func Draw(dst Image, r image.Rectangle, src image.Image, sp image.Point, op Op)`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#Draw), you do not need anything from a [`Quantizer`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#Quantizer)

You need to provide a [`draw.Image`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#Image) implementation, and other data.
See an example in [`soniakeys/quant`](https://github.com/soniakeys/quant), where:

- The `quantizers` satisfy the draw.Quantizer interface of the standard library, [like this one](https://github.com/soniakeys/quant/blob/0a3861b3bd925b434c67c93a15633ced8475092d/mean/mean.go#L70-L77).
- The ditherer [satisfies the `draw.Drawer` interface](https://github.com/soniakeys/quant/blob/0a3861b3bd925b434c67c93a15633ced8475092d/sierra.go#L18-L25) of the standard library.

If this is still not working, you would need an alternative like [`esimov/colorquant`](https://github.com/esimov/colorquant).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly. I added some details into my question just now. 
Well, I mean, I need to pass some data from `Quantizer` into the `Drawer` to make my algorithm faster.

Comment: @CuteReimu I just edited the links to add examples

Comment: @CuteReimu To my knowledge, Quantize returns a Palette, not an indexing map.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. `Quantize` returns a `Palette`, which is a slice of `Color`. But if I don't have this indexing map, my algorithm in `Drawer` will be slow. So I think maybe the interface is not so good, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I'd better show [the code](https://github.com/CuteReimu/neuquant/blob/master/Palette.go) . `AnalyzePalette()` returns an indexing map and a `Palette`. In `WritePalette()`, I can just look up the index in the indexing map. I don't need to calculate again.

Comment: @CuteReimu OK, but that does not look like the interface declared in `draw`.

Comment: @CuteReimu The point being, this does *not* implement `draw.Quantizer` and `draw.Drawer`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what troubles me. I don't know whether there is a way to satisfy these interfaces and make my algorithm faster at the same time.